# Is the PHP/MySQL code different when using local web hosting (XAMPP)? I don't want to change my code much when I actually go live

Tags: php, mysql, apache, xampp, localhost

I'm using local webhosting via XAMPP. I'm now preparing to learn MySQL and PHP so that I can get a database set up for users to be able to log in, etc.

However, I'm worried that because I'm using local hosting, the code is going to be a lot different than it would be if I had real hosting. Therefore, when the time comes to actually go live, I'm scared that like 90% of my PHP/MySQL code will have to be changed.

Please let me know if the code will have to be different just because my hosting is local. If so, please also let me know to what degree the difference will be (i.e. will I have to change EVERY line of code to suit the local hosting, or only like 5%?)

Comment: If your localhost use same php & mysql version as server there will be no different  in code.

Comment: if you try not to use depreciated functions in your code, and won't put database connection credentials all over the place, you don't have to worry, you may need to change only the login details to the database when you move to actual server.